# How to use MySQL with Python in a client server setup

Tags: python, mysql, server

I'd like to develop a python project in client - server style.
My Python code will be deployed on a client machine and the MySQL database on the server, so all connections need to flow through a network connection.

I know how to use Python with MySQL with basics such as creating tables and queries etc, however I wanted to learn how to connect my python project to the database over a network protocol.

I searched on Google or YouTube, but only found resources that use a local database connection.

Where can I find Python resources (article, blog, sample, tutorial or video) that explains how to connect to MySQL via the network?

Answer (score 0):

You have server with MySQL database running on it and a python client-application, which needs data from the database?

I think usually client software never connects directly to the database (for security reasons). Instead the client communicates with a server-application (maybe over a **REST-API**).

[How i meant it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpl1E.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is seems to be a good guide.

https://pynative.com/python-mysql-tutorial/

I tried PyMySql quickly. It works. Only problem is it is in Beta. https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

So I suggest you try the **MySQL Connector Python** will be slightly painful to setup initially but it comes from the vendor. so you can trust it a bit better.

**or alternatively** https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

```
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysql

try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='10.1.1.1 (remote server ip or hostname)',
                            user='db_user_name',
                            password='db_password',
                            db='name_of_db',
                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    sql = "select * from users"

    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "select * from users"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
except Exception as inst:
    print(str(inst))
finally:
    conn.close()
```